# Advice on drawing 3/4 view perspective of a vehicle

Tags: drawing, perspective, sprite

(Reposted here under the advice of @Philipp)

What is a good method to make a 3/4 view car, truck or other vehicle going around a corner?" As stated above I have a firm grasp on how to do N/S E/W just not in between. I find it easier to learn via example and tutorial.

---

I am currently in the process of creating a first in media that I am aware of a sprite comic series based off of the Transformers Mythos. Some of you may have seen info about this before and it's taking time but I am fully ready to grow my skills in the pixel art field as I go along with putting my own spin on the classic war for Cybertron.

Having said that I can finally bring up a trouble area I need advice from the top tier spriters so I can actually make the next step. So I want to ask some advice on methodology for sprite making. The primary style I plan to use being a 3/4 view comparable to Chrono Trigger or the more recent Stardew Valley and the indie game Bot Vice.

I am having great difficulty understanding the best way to take the sprites smoothly around a corner. Let's say you were playing a racing game with said perspective for me all would be fine in spriting until a curve came up which would require the sprite to lean into a in between set of frames between North/South and East/West the four cardinal directions. (Studying Retro City Rampage's set up I've found a full smooth turn can be made in three frames) I can do fine but Diagonals (all variations between too) are something I need advice possibly even tutoring on as my comic will definitely have to have that angle whether it be Optimus spining out, Bumblebee taking a curve too sharp or just a scenic view where the into curve looks best.

Now I'm not limiting myself to just 3/4 view but for the most part unless it's a larger scene or is better shown in another angle it is what I'm using.

Comment: How do they solve it in the examples you mention? That would be a good start.